# Trying to install Ubuntu on partitioned HD

Tags: installation, partitioning

I have a Samsung 1TB HD partitioned into 4 primary partions. I want to use:
Partition 1 for Win XP
Partition 2 for Win Vista
Partition 3 for Ubuntu
Partition 4 for Kubuntu.
I have partitioned the drive while trying to install Ubuntu.
No OS is yet installed. I decide to start with Ubuntu because I know I can use Ubuntu to partition the drive.
So after the partitioning (all 4 drives are ext4 and 250GB each), I set the mount point for partition 3 to'/' but no mount point to any of the other partitions. Boot loader (Devive for boot loader installation) is set to '/dev/sdf ATA SAMSUNG HD 103UJ' (1.0 TB).
When I click 'Install Now' I get the warning message: 'No mount point is assigned for the ext4 file system in partition#1 of SCSI7 (0,0,0) (sdf)'
So What ams I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to install windows os first because they will overwrite important bits like the MBR.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Ok. How do I partition the disk before I can install the windows? It seems the patitioning is part of installing Ubuntu; Can I just partition the disc, then quit and install win OS?

Comment: Using the live CD in try mode. When it loads there should be gparted or disks .  if not you will have to go partway through install.https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/partitioning